# Doesn't seem like my command is working in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, botframework

The command is executed, although the terminal says the command doesn't exist.
Not sure what's up as this is my first discord bot, I know a little bit of python, so I am sorry for taking up your guys's time, really.

Thank you for the help though!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= ':')
game = discord.Game("with the API")
#list of banned words
filtered_words = ['bad words']
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello I am online and ready!")

bot.run('token')

#Group message clearing
@bot.command(aliases=['c'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=1):
        await ctx.channel.purge(Limit = amount)
        await ctx.reply(f'Deleted {clear} messages')

#auto mod
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in msg.context:
            await msg.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(msg)

@bot.event
async def on_disconnect():
    print("I seem to be getting disconnected, one minute!")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(memeber):
    print(f'Weclome {memeber} to the server, please enjoy your stay!')

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    msg.send(" <:raysQ:835686467844964395> ")
```

Comment: Could you post the output/error you are seeing in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bot.run` part should be at the end of the file. It's.the entry point to the loop.

Also please regenerate your token before someone else can use it.

Comment: Oh, thanks I edited the question and changed my token, thanks for letting me know :D